# Trouble mounting USB devices to Windows 10 VirtualBox VM

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am experiencing issues connecting USB devices to my Windows 10 VM on VirtualBox. 
My host is a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop running
a fully up-to-date Kubuntu 19.0 (Disco Dingo).

I have also installed the VirtualBox extension pack and enabled USB 2.0 device support under the VM settings.

Other features such as the guest add-ons, shared folders and network bridging work perfectly fine.

If I want to add a USB device on the VirtualBox toolbar, it just says no devices available.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

USB settings of VM:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your VM, click settings, go at USB, ensure that `Enable USB Controler` is checked, and change the USB version of your controller.

Then try again.

You may also want to check if your user is added to the vboxusers group since additional permissions are needed for using USB devices.

Comment: It was like that already. I'm not that stupid lol

Comment: At your USB Device filter list can you see your device? When you press + is the USB drive available at your Host machine?

Comment: No not at all. That's what's bugging me. I'm not sure if my host system is blocking exposing USB devices to the VM.

Comment: Check if you have to add your users at the vboxusers group, I believe that if you try some google search you will find more information about how to add your user to the VirtualBox group in order to be able to share USB resources

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks so much for the help. I found this command: sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER     Link to thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377778/how-to-add-users-to-vboxusers

Comment: Please [edit] the correct answer into the answer.

Comment: I use Windows 10 as host system, do I need to add my user to a VB group? I can see the device in the USB Filter list, it is scan disk. In Device Manager, I see AMD USB Hostcontroller 3, so I activated USB 3 above the filter. I reinstalled Virtual Box with Choco, what else can I do?